# SQL Server Express 2005 cannot connect

Tags: sql-server, timeout, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server Express 2005 install on a godaddy virtual terminal which currently is only connected to(locally with mgt studio) every few days or so.  Every time i try to connect I get a cannot connect to SQL Server error and after a restart it I can connect just fine locally. I was wondering if there is a timeout setting or something that I am missing that I need to change so that if it is not connected to for a while it does not required a restart?  any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have the database AUTO_CLOSE property ON.

See [Setting Database Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As @John Sansom says there is an AUTO_CLOSE option, however from memory (it's an Express feature which I don't use often) I think this only causes a single database to be unloaded from memory.  You can tell if the database is being unloaded (and re-loaded on demand) by looking in the Application Event Log.

Since Management Studio by default will try to connect to the master database which isn't unloaded though I don't think this is your problem.  Again, I'd suggest looking through the event log to see if there's anything obvious in there?  I assume that when you can't connect the MS SQL service is still 'running' ?